# Is there a Map I can use that will prevent .equals() duplicates?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, identity, equality

I want a `Map<?, ?>`  which will prevent duplicates, but not only memory duplicates, but duplicates where everything in the object has the same value, i.e. where .equals() == true. Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like a `Set`.

Comment: try `Set` for avoiding dupes

Comment: Do you mean duplicate keys or duplicate values?  The standard maps (e.g., HashMap) already has only one entry per key, and compares keys with .equals.

Comment: Use Comparator, I believe it will solve your problem

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor So your positive it compares with `.equals()` instead of the `==` operator?

Comment: @LukeyBoyIsXen It's all in the documentation.  The documentation for [`public V HashMap#get(Object key)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) says "More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key `k` to a value `v` such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`, then this method returns `v`; otherwise it returns `null`. (There can be at most one such mapping.)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Map interface specifies that the comparison of keys is equality (`.equals`):

> `public interface Map<K,V>`
>
> #### [public V get(Object key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object))
>
> …. More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key `k` to a
>   value `v` such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`, then this
>   method returns `v`; otherwise it returns `null`. (There can be at most one
>   such mapping.)

Of course, that's *documentation* of the interface.  The Java type system can't actually *enforce* that that behavior holds.  Most implementations of Map respect it, though.  For instance, that's the behavior you'll see in a HashMap.

There *is* an implementation of Map that is based on identity (`==`) rather than equality (`.equals`), though. It's called [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html).  Its documentation explicitly calls out the fact that this behavior is not typical for implementations of Map, and that, in fact, it *violates* the contract of Map (emphasis present in original):

> ```
> public class IdentityHashMap<K,V>
> extends AbstractMap<K,V>
> implements Map<K,V>, Serializable, Cloneable
> ```
>
> … **This class is not a general-purpose Map implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's
>   general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when
>   comparing objects. This class is designed for use only in the rare
>   cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required.**

Answer (score 0):

You are searching a **birectional mapping**, use Guava's [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

That is: mapping as a bijective function:

```
y = map.get(x)
x = map.inverse.get(y)
```

---

***Correction:***

As @JoshuaTaylor commented, it seems I have misunderstood the question.

Just maybe, maybe, what really is wanted though, is having no multiple instances of equal objects.

```
class Unique {

    private static Map<Object, Object> identityMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static <T> T share(T object, Class<T> type) {
        Object old = identityMap.get(object);
        if (old == null) {
            old = object;
            identityMap.put(old, old);
        }
        return type.cast(old);
    }
}
```

With usage:

```
Xxx x = ...
x = Unique.share(x, Xxx.class);
```

Which causes `x` to be the first equal instance.

Probable a weak reference map would be nicer.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP is looking for.  Given that OP mentions "not only memory duplicates", it sounds like OP expects implementations of Map to be based on ==/identity rather than .equals/equality.   There is [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) that is based on ==/identity, but typical implementations of Map are based on .equals/equality.